# « Tomber en amour » v. « tomber amoureux »

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, québec

En lisant un roman, j'ai trouvé un passage où l'écrivain avait utilisé « tomber en amour ». Je n'ai jamais entendu « tomber en amour » mais j'entends « tomber amoureux » très souvent. Avait-il raison ?

Comment: Sorti de mon chapeau, je dirais que « tomber en amour » est typiquement québecois. Voyons ce qu'en pensent les intéressés.

Comment: Est-ce-à-dire que tu travailles du chapeau? Ce dernier fait certainement partie d'un costume d'évpoque.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

« Tomber en amour » est une expression très utilisée au Québec. C'est un calque de l'anglais *to fall in love*. La même chose s'applique pour l'expression « être en amour », calque de *to be in love*.

Les *Clefs du français pratique de Termium*, la banque de données terminologiques et linguistiques du gouvernement du Canada, contient [la fiche suivante](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_a&page=9QiYjwKuwAAA.html#zz9QiYjwKuwAAA) :

> **Être en amour/tomber en amour**
>
> Calques de *to be in love/to fall in love* à remplacer, dans la langue écrite, par **être amoureux, être amoureuse; tomber amoureux, tomber amoureuse**. Ces expressions sont toutefois largement utilisées au Canada dans la langue orale.

Comment: Intéressant, ne connaissant pas l'expression, de prime abord elle sonne négative à mes oreilles, à mi chemin entre _"tomber au combat"_ et _"malheureux en amour"_.

Comment: Oui c'est un cousin de "faire du sens", "prendre une marche"...

Comment: L'expression doit aussi être utilisée en France, par exemple Jacques Higelin l'utilise dans sa chanson `Tombé du ciel`.